# Без кавычек не работает

Tags: apache, php

Здравствуйте, я поднял связку apache+php+mysql и столкнулся с такой проблемы и не знаю куда копать. 
Если я указываю путь без кавычек не работает php скрипт если ставлю то всё работает к примеру:

include ./config.php; - не работает, *PHP Parse error: sintax error, unexpected '.' in /home/trulala*

include "./config.php"; - всё работает.

Что мне настроить что-бы и без кавычек работало.

Comment: Вообще в таких случаях надо копать в сторону документации, с чего вы  решили, что оно должно работать без кавычек?  
Что настроить? ну взять исходники php и переписать ихх так, чтобы работало без кавычек :)

Answer (score 6):

С чего вы взяли, что оно *должно* работать без кавычек? Директива `include` принимает параметром **строку**, в которой содержится имя файла, который нужно подключить. А строки PHP, как известно, всегда берутся в кавычки.

[Документация](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.include.php)

Comment: Просто у меня на другие сервера работает и без кавычек, по этому и задал такой вопрос.

Comment: Какие другие сервера? Какая версия PHP? Так работать не должно, внимательно присмотритесь к тем серверам, с ними что-то не то.